# Function takes 2D arrarys, returns 1D array,

Tags: arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write a function that takes a two dimensional arrary, does some element-wise maths on it, and spits out a one dimensional array as a result.
I've tried this but it doesn't work, and I don't know why:

Function:

```
double underlying_actionable(double values[2][20])  
{
    double actionables [20] { };
    for( int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
    {
        actionables[i] = min(values[i][0], values[i][1]);
    }
    return actionables;
}
```

Call:

```
double actionables [20];
actionables = underlying_actionable(underliers);
```

Comment: According to the declaration, the function returns a double value, not a 1D array of doubles.

Answer (score 0):

The method `underlying_actionable` is returning a double value instead of a double array.

If you are working on C/C++, then you have to use pointers to do so.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_return_arrays_from_function.htm

On any other language just use `[]` after the datatype of the function at the time of function declaration and definition.

```
datatype[] function_name(args)
{
    body
}
```